# Is this strategy pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

A little background:

In the system I am developing, there are various types of CSV files to be read and saved the contents in different database tables. Since this is about changing behavior based on inputs, I studies the decorator, and strategy patterns and came up with the following solution for my system.

First I created following interfaces.

- `ICDRMapper` reads each line from a given CSV file and maps to a object after running validations/modifications (if any). There are many concrete implementations for each CDR type.
- `ICDRReader` takes the input CSV file and reads each line and pass it to the mapper. Each reader implementation is decorated with MEF metadata so that the `ICDREngine` can locate the correct one on the fly. This interface also has many implementations for each CDR Type.
- `ICDREngine` implementation uses MEF metadata to locate a matching `ICDRReader` implementation. This usually has only one implementation.

Then, I have created a `AbstractCDRReader` and `AbstractCDRMapper` and used decorator pattern to delegate specific implementations to different concrete classes.

`AbstractCDRReader` selects the correct `ICDRMapper` implementation based on MEF metadata just like the engine does.

Following is a generated class diagram.

[image: generated class diagram]

So my questions are,

- **Is this strategy pattern or a different one?**
- **Is there any way I could improve this design so that next time I need to read a whole new different CSV file, I can do the implementation very quickly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've described the architecture of a part of a system. It uses few design patterns:

- **abstract factory** (*ICDREngine* the process of creation concrete implementations of *ICDRReader*, *ICDRMapper*),
- 2 implementations of **Strategy** patern (*ICDRReader*, *ICDRMapper* hierarchies),
- you also mentioned **Decorator** (though I don't see it from the class diagram - it is either incomplete or you misunderstood what is called Decorator).
- The relation between Mapper and Reader hierarchies represents **Bridge** pattern if I'm not mistaken.

As for me your architecture looks good and flexible. I'm not sure what you expect to improve for easier adding ability to read new CSV format - currently all you need is add new implementation of ICDRReader, don't you? So it is easy enough from my point of view and nothing should be improved for this particular 'problem'.

Comment: Yes, As you said there I have used abstract factory pattern. Okay, after reading more about the decorator pattern, I think I might really be using the builder there as @OndrejJanacek mentioned below.

Yes, adding a new ICDRReader and a ICDRMapper and export them using MEF with relevant metadata is what i need to do now inorder to introduce a new csv format. I was thinking along the lines of not having to recompile the code again and again when I want to add a new one.

Comment: Extending without recompiling is helpful when it is regular, user-initiated procedure. If it's happening not so often, I wouldn't recommend adding so much flexibility as it will complicate your system and increase development time few times. If you really need it, it may cause big changes in this architectire: implement some configurable CSV reader based on defined metadata and reimplement all other readers as a partial case. Code generation may help optimize your code to generate very fast readers on the fly. In my 6+ years development experience I saw such things only once.

Comment: Probably it may be an overkill. but, that's exactly what I was thinking. Implementing a configurable CSV reader in conjunction with a rule engine so that I can define metadata and the rules on how to validate/parse each field in an XML file along with the new CSV specific metadata. And thank you so much for your invaluable insight.

Answer (score 3):

Choosing an architecture should not be too much about design pattern but rather about logical thinking. **Do you feel that what you have come up with is easily extendible for new types of CSV files?** If you do than forget about which pattern it is and be sure you can stand up for your design and you are able to explain the decision to team-mates.

That being said, it can very well be the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. It's not obvious from the schema what the resulting product of mappers is but I think that the builder could be applied.  [image]

Basically, `AbstractMapper` is the `Builder` part, concrete mappers are `ConreteBuilder`s and there surely is some `Director` in your architecture as well. It even sound like the builder. "*I have an input data. I need something responsible for parsing it based on various parameters and create a product used inside the rest of my application.*" And when you think about it, you are basically building something, taking unfamiliar data and building known objects - it leads to creational patterns.

As for the readers, it could be the same, it could by the strategy or something else. It depends how you think about it and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Yes, I do feel that it's now fairly easy to introduce a new csv type. infact now I can code it in a different class lib and plug it into the system because I'm using MEF. Oh..now I get it.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a combination of patterns. I think we're missing information on how the decision to switch between Mobile, ADSL and Fixed is made. The strongest fit seems to be for the abstract factory:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

It's important to remember that patterns aren't exclusive, and you will probably use elements of other patterns subtly when writing good OO code.

Comment: Actually I'm using MEF along with metadata exports to find a matching reader/mapper.